# Player input prediction pseudoCode

Tags: probability

I am making a simple game where a player has to select either heads or tails.
So let heads be 0 and tails be 1. now suppose they choose a sequence like this:
0,1,0,1,0,1...   or
0,0,1,0,0,1...
So is there any way i can find the pattern mathematically and guess the next prediction.
Eventhough i am coding in python, a pseudocode will be more than enough

If computer guesses right,it will get a point and the other way around

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the longest previous match(es) as predictors:

Given previous inputs $x_1,\ldots, x_n$.

1. If $n=0$, output a random guess; perhaps you also prefer to output a random guess if $n=1$; otherwise continue
2. Build a list $L\leftarrow\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$
3. Let $d\leftarrow 1$
4. Let $L'\leftarrow\{\,i\in L\mid i>d\land x_{i-d}=x_{n+1-d}\,\}$
5. If $L'$ is non-empty, set $L\leftarrow L'$, $d\leftarrow d+1$, and go back to step 4.
6. Pick a unformly random element $r\in L$ and output $x_r$

Comment: Sorry,I am a math noob. I didn't understood half of the symbols used here. Any help : (

Comment: Okay,now I understood what you meant. I have a question-          what can be the value of i here? Is it from -infinite to infinite or is there a limit to where the value of i can be checked for.